# Converting Emacs Org-Mode Table to Mathematica Datastructure(s)?

Tags: list-manipulation, conversion

Is there a way automatically/programmatically convert an org-mode table

```
| Name  | Start Date       | End Date         | Notes            |
|-------+------------------+------------------+------------------|
| Name1 | [2018-12-19 Wed] | [2019-12-19 Thu] | Some notes.      |
| Name2 | [2016-12-19 Wed] | [2018-12-19 Thu] | Some more notes. |
```

to its corresponding Wolfram datastructure? Perhaps something like

```
data = {Labeled[Interval[{DateObject[{2018,12,19}], DateObject[{2019,12,19}]}], "Name1: Some notes."], Labeled[Interval[{DateObject[{2016,12,19}], DateObject[{2018,12,19}]}], "Name2: Some more notes."]}
```

which can be used like

```
TimelinePlot[data]
```

> [image]

Comment: Good question. I would like to mention that org-tables can be exported to CSV files, and those CSV files can be ingested in Mathematica.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your org-mode table is in a plain text file, this approach should work

```
org = ReadList["orgmode.txt", String];

a = StringSplit[org[[3 ;;]], "|"];
b = a /. s_String :> StringTrim[s];
c = b /. s_String :>
   StringReplace[s, "[" ~~ ymd__ ~~ " " ~~ __ ~~ "]" :> ymd]

data = Labeled[
     Interval[ { DateObject[#[[2]]], DateObject[#[[3]]] } ],
     #[[1]] <> ": " <> #[[4]]  ]& /@ c;

TimelinePlot[data]
```