# Converting Org-Mode Table into Wolfram Dataset

Tags: dataset

Simula to [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/211667/converting-emacs-org-mode-table-to-mathematica-datastructures), is there a way to convert an org-mode table (say in the form of a string) to a Wolfram Dataset? So that  for example this:

```
| Title          | Notes            |
|----------------+------------------|
| A title.       | Some notes.      |
| Another title. | Some more notes. |
```

gets converted into

```
Dataset[{<| "Title" -> "A title.", "Notes" -> "Some notes." |>, <| "Title" -> "Another title.", "Notes" -> "Some more notes."  }]
```

?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
orgmode = "| Title          | Notes            |
  |----------------+------------------|
  | A title.       | Some notes.      |
  | Another title. | Some more notes. |";

{keys, vals} = {First @ #, Rest @ #} &[DeleteCases[""] /@ StringTrim /@ 
   StringSplit[Drop[StringSplit[orgmode, "\n"], {2}], "|"]]
```

> {{"Title", "Notes"}, {{"A title.", "Some notes."}, {"Another title.", 
>      "Some more notes."}}}

```
ds = Dataset[AssociationThread[keys, #] & /@ vals]
```

[image]

Comment: kglr: I am getting the following error w/AssociationThread when using this with the example: [here](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/user-900a994f-78ab-4931-b18e-353eff4d0b33/548021349767080157182480033805884330297170249048.png).

Comment: @George, pls try  the updated version.

Comment: kglr: Fixed! Thanks!